# How can I delete all pods of specific deployments of specific namespaces?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I am looking for a way to delete all pods of specific deployments of specific namespaces. In other words, given:

> x - list of namespaces
>   y - list of deployments

```
for i in x:
  for j in y:
    delete all pods of deployment j in namespace i
```

I would be happy if someone knows how to do it in bash commands.

Thanks!

Comment: If you delete the deployments, it will delete the pods. Is that not sufficient for your use case?

Comment: No, I want to restart pods in order that new configs will be loaded to them from configmap

Comment: How are you getting data from the ConfigMaps to the Pods? Can you share your Deployment YAMLs? In some cases, changes to ConfigMap data can propogate to running Pods without requiring restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe something like this will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAMESPACES=( n1 n2 n3 )
DEPLOYMENTS=( dep1 dep2 dep3 )

for i in "${NAMESPACES[@]}"
do
  for x in "${DEPLOYMENTS[@]}"
  do
     # Get the pods in the deployment
     PODS=$(kubectl -n $i get pods --no-headers | awk '{print $1}' | grep $x | tr '\n' ' ')
     kubectl -n $i delete pods $PODS
  done
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally you do this with label selectors. You would put something in the template metadata like `labels: {app: foo}` and then `kubectl delete pod --all-namespaces -l app=foo`.

Comment: 1. I don't want to do it to all namespaces, only part of them.  2. can I do "or" condition between labels?

Comment: or condition: `-l "app in (foo, bar)"`

Comment: I don't think there is any single CLI call which will do 2 namespaces, either you need to do all and factor things into your selector or two calls with `-n whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want "single line" solution you can use bash's braces expansion together with [Kubernetes' Labels and Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/):

```
eval 'kubectl delete pods --namespace='{n1,n2,n3}' --selector='{app=foo1,app=foo2,svc=svc1,svc=svc2}';'
```

Another way to write that:

```
eval 'kubectl delete pods -n '{n1,n2,n3}' -l '{"'app in (foo1,foo2)'","'svc in (svc1,svc2)'"}';'
```

Answer (score 1):

You've explained in comments that your use case is for your `Pods` to pick up new data from `ConfigMaps`. For this purpose, you do not need to directly delete any Pods.

If your `Pods` get data from `ConfigMaps` via a mounted volume, and you're not using the `subPath` feature, then `ConfigMap` changes get picked up automatically and you don't need to do anything to your `Deployments` or `Pods` (you might have to wait a minute or so for the change to propagate). For this to work, of course, your application within your `Pod` needs to watch for changes to the mounted files and incorporate them when changes appear.

If, on the other hand, your `Pods` are extracting values via, say, environment variables, then you simply need to restart your `Deployments`, for which there is a more convenient `kubectl` command than deletion, in fact you don't need to muck around directly with `Pods` at all. Use `kubectl rollout restart`:

```
namespaces="ns1 ns2"
deployments="dep1 dep2"

for ns in ${namespaces}; do
  for dep in ${deployments}; do
    kubectl rollout restart deployment/"${dep}" --namespace="${ns}"
  done
done
```